# Difference between nouns "strip" and "stripe"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Is there a specific difference between the nouns "strip" and "stripe", especially in the context of "a strip(e) of paper"? Are both equivalent or do they carry specific meanings?

Comment: A stripe is "a long narrow band or strip, typically of the same width throughout its length, differing in color or texture from the surface on either side of it", and a strip is a "a long, narrow piece of cloth, paper, plastic, or some other material".

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar not so different, then? Feel free to answer :D

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, then.

Comment: A stripe is a continuous constant-width wide line (or wider) on a surface. A strip is a long thin piece by itself. A strip can have stripes on it, but the other way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stripe is "a long narrow band or strip, typically of the same width throughout its length, differing in color or texture from the surface on either side of it", and a strip is a "a long, narrow piece of cloth, paper, plastic, or some other material".

These two definitions are not very different from each other, but one must take into consideration the fact that a stripe is in fact a strip with a color or texture difference from the surface (in this case, paper) on the other side of one side of the paper. (Being a mathematician, I can't help but add - these definitions are not accurate for a Mobius strip!).

*Reference*: Strip, Stripe. 2013. Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press. 27 January, 2014.

Comment: A strip can exist independently of other objects/surfaces; a stripe is a feature of some other substrate.  Confusingly, a strip (of cloth, for instance) can be used to form a stripe (on a uniform, for example).

Comment: @MT_Head: That's true, and as I've written in my answer, "a stripe is in fact a strip with a color or texture difference from the paper on the other side of one side of the paper".

Comment: Would you mind augmenting your answer with some references (dictionaries etc.)?

Comment: @YvesKlett: This definition has been obtained from Oxford dictionaries.

Comment: Please cite your sources for quotations (with a link, if available, otherwise a bibliographic citation). Answers should not contain unsourced quotations.

Answer (score 8):

"strip" has several meanings. One meaning describes the form of something: something that is long and small.
You can speak of a strip of paper, cloth, metal or a strip of land, as already said.

"stripe" is a colour design. A shirt can have stripes, a flag can have stripes. The US-American flag is called "Stars and Stripes".